# Finding cells which fullfill condition of geometric decline in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a dataset of a rockfall simulation which shows all cells (green), where rocks would be deposited. Cell Value ist the geometric decline (The direct angle between release cell and final cell).

I would like to work out all possible release areas under consideration of the DEM (release cell must be higher than deposite cell and directly be "reachable" with the angle value (which is not always possible, e.g. valley ground, gullies, ground edges).

I was thinking about using something linke proximity and then not using distance but the angle values butdon't get to a reasonable solution.

The picture shows the situation: 
red: potential release area; green: deposit area
[image: yellow-red: potentual release area; green: deposit area]